# Laravel: не выводятся ошибки, если их много, баг?

Tags: php, laravel

Homestead, Laravel 6, Русский язык, файл руссификатор валидатора https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

Проблема: при большом количестве ошибок (больше 5) не отображаются ошибки, не записываются в сессию. 
Попробовал другие языки, еще нашел подобную проблему с si языком, там не запиcывается больше 7.

С en все ок.

От файла перевода вроде не зависит, так как если оставить только поле required - ничего не изменится.

Кейс на пустом приложении Laravel 6 :

Делаю большую форму:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form class="form" method="post" action="{{route('testvalid')}}">
        @csrf
        <input class="form-control" name="field1" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field2" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field3" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field4" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field5" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field6" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field7" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field8" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field9" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field10" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field11" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Контроллер обработчик:

```
 public function testvalidpost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'field1'=>['required'],
            'field2'=>['required'],
            'field3'=>['required'],
            'field4'=>['required'],
            'field5'=>['required'],
            'field6'=>['required'],
            'field7'=>['required'],
            'field8'=>['required'],
            'field9'=>['required'],
            'field10'=>['required'],
            'field11'=>['required'],
        ]);
        echo 111;
    }
```

Comment: Странно как-то, у меня кейс был с формой на 80 полей, и все отображались... От самого языка по идее вообще ничего не должно зависеть - это просто подстановка.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вот собственно полный кейс. Пустое приложение и код выше. Почему так - сам не пойму. Причем именно языки меняю - на одних работает, ну других нет. Беру русский - 5 полей и меньше заполняю - работает. Заполняю больше  - все, пустота. Валиадция не проходит, но и сообщения не выводятся

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено, нужно установить SESSION_DRIVER=file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614407/laravel-6-9-0-validation-php-translated-messages-not-showing-if-they-do-not-star

Странно, что оно вообще в куках стоит по умолчанию.